# Magento: Show two products on the product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to show two different products on the product view page. Basically, after displaying the first product like it normally would, the page should then show another product with all it's details, images and of course the "Add to Cart" button.

Both products should be fully displayed on the product view page, so I can't use any of the existing blocks like `catalog/product_list_related` or `catalog/product_list_upsell`.

My idea was to simply add another `catalog/product_view` block to the `catalog_product_view` layout definition, like so:

**catalog.xml:**

```
   <layout version="0.1.0">
        ...
        <catalog_product_view translate="label">
            ...
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                    ...
                </block>
            </reference>
            ...
            <!-- Changes start here -->
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info2" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                    <action method="setProductId"><product_id>123</product_id></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>
```

However, this does not seem to work. Various elements of the block don't seem to load correctly, as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

All the product images are missing as well as the price and the buttons. Also, my call to `setProductId()` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago now, but did you ever find the solution? I am facing the same problem :[

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I ever did. I went a completely other route with that project to avoid that problem. Best of luck though!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this catalog.xml, then magento usa base catalog.xml